# SOLVED - Debug Darkice to understand why is not connecting to shoutcast

Tags: linux, audio, streaming, shoutcast

---

I'm trying to connect to a **shoutcast server** from a **darkice** client using Ubuntu. This is my configuration:

```
#this section describes general aspects of the live streaming session
[general]
duration        = 0        # duration of encoding, in seconds. 0 means forever
bufferSecs      = 10          # size of internal slip buffer, in seconds
reconnect       = yes       # reconnect to the server(s) if disconnected
realtime        = no       # run the encoder with POSIX realtime priority
rtprio          = 3         # scheduling priority for the realtime threads

# this section describes the audio input that will be streamed
[input]
device           = hw:CARD=PCH,DEV=0
sampleRate      = 44100                 # sample rate in Hz. try 11025, 22050 or 44100
bitsPerSample   = 16                    # bits per sample. try 16
channel         = 2                     # channels. 1 = mono, 2 = stereo

# this section describes a streaming connection to an IceCast2 server
# there may be up to 8 of these sections, named [icecast2-0] ... [icecast2-7]
# these can be mixed with [icecast-x] and [shoutcast-x] sections
[shoutcast-0]
bitrateMode     = cbr
format          = mp3
bitrate         = 96
quality         = 1.0
server          = xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
port            = 8020
password        = xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
name            = Radio website
url             = https://www.mywebsite.it
genre           = live
public          = no
```

But when I run

```
darkice -v 10 -c /etc/darkice-shoutcast.cfg
```

It only shows this, without errors or similar, but there is no streaming at the url. Using **BUTT** it works. I've also tested with 8021 instead of 8020 for port (8020 it's the port number given by the provider) but no luck.

```
DarkIce 1.4 live audio streamer, http://code.google.com/p/darkice/
Copyright (c) 2000-2007, Tyrell Hungary, http://tyrell.hu/
Copyright (c) 2008-2013, Akos Maroy and Rafael Diniz
This is free software, and you are welcome to redistribute it 
under the terms of The GNU General Public License version 3 or
any later version.

Using config file: /etc/darkice-shoutcast.cfg
18-May-2021 12:02:28 Using ALSA DSP input device: hw:CARD=PCH,DEV=0
18-May-2021 12:02:28 buffer size:  1764000
18-May-2021 12:02:28 encoding
18-May-2021 12:02:28 MultiThreadedConnector :: transfer, bytes 0
18-May-2021 12:02:28 MultiThreadedConnector :: ThreadData :: threadFunction, was (thread, priority, type):  0x5568a502c010 0 SCHED_OTHER
18-May-2021 12:02:28 MultiThreadedConnector :: ThreadData :: threadFunction, now is (thread, priority, type):  0x5568a502c010 0 SCHED_OTHER
```

**ADDENDUM**
I've used tcpdump to understand what could be and I just see something similar to "invalid password"

```
: Flags [P.], cksum 0xc379 (correct), seq 1:19, ack 3090, win 294, options [nop,nop,TS val 3348978428 ecr 531576376], length 18
E..F1O@.1.3'.}.......T.Jq.k.D......&.y.....
..Z...68Invalid Passwor
```

Suggestions on how to better debug or fix this?

**SOLVED**
It seems the error is related to the password and wrong parsing of the config file, so I've written it without spaces

```
[shoutcast-0]
bitrateMode     = cbr
format          = mp3
bitrate         = 96
quality         = 1.0
server          = xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
port            = 8020
password=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
name            = Radio website
url             = https://www.mywebsite.it
genre           = live
public          = no
```